# Python 3.4. Código que busca en una secuencia de enteros aquellos que son el resultado la suma de dos cuadrados

Tags: python, optimización

Como práctica de `Python` escribo un código que busca en una secuencia qué enteros son el resultado de la suma de dos (o más) cuadrados.
Funciona bien pero me surgen las siguientes dudas.

1. Empiezo con un generador y una lista vacía. Los números se van comparando con el contenido de la lista y añadiendo a esta si cumplen ciertas condiciones. ¿Estoy en lo cierto si esto es más eficiente que si creo inicialmente una lista (en lugar del generador)?. O depende de si en el primer caso prefiero más memoria disponible o, en el segundo, menos procesamiento de datos? (No sé si me he explicado bien).
2. ¿Cómo se podría mejorar el código? Me gustaría ver si alguien más avanzado (yo soy aficionado y autodidacta) puede encontrar una solución notablemente más simple. Seguro que he hecho alguna tontería.

El programa es el siguiente:

```
def gen_raices(min, max):
    lista = []

    # Comprueba entre tres opciones:
    # op1 = El entero no está en lista.
    # op2 = Está en lista pero de suma distintas.
    # op3 = Está en lista pero con misma suma.
    def comprueba (r1, r2):
        for d in range(len(lista)):
            if lista[d][0] == r1 + r2:
                for t in range(1,len(lista[d])):
                    if r1 in lista[d][t]:
                        return 3
                return (2, d)
        return 1

    # Añade a la lista las sumas de raices.
    e1 = 1
    while e1 ** 2 <= max:
        for e2 in range(1, max):
            r1 = e1 ** 2
            r2 = e2 ** 2
            if r1 + r2 <= max and r1 + r2 >= min:
                comp = comprueba(r1, r2)
                if comp == 1:
                    lista.append([r1 + r2, (r1, r2)])
                elif comp == 3:
                    continue
                else:
                    lista[comp[1]].append((r1, r2))
        e1 += 1
    lista.sort()
    return lista

print(gen_raices(1,100))
```

el resultado es:

```
[[2, (1, 1)], [5, (1, 4)], [8, (4, 4)], [10, (1, 9)], [13, (4, 9)], [17, (1, 16)], [18, (9, 9)], [20, (4, 16)], [25, (9, 16)], [26, (1, 25)], [29, (4, 25)], [32, (16, 16)], [34, (9, 25)], [37, (1, 36)], [40, (4, 36)], [41, (16, 25)], [45, (9, 36)], [50, (1, 49), (25, 25)], [52, (16, 36)], [53, (4, 49)], [58, (9, 49)], [61, (25, 36)], [65, (1, 64), (16, 49)], [68, (4, 64)], [72, (36, 36)], [73, (9, 64)], [74, (25, 49)], [80, (16, 64)], [82, (1, 81)], [85, (4, 81), (36, 49)], [89, (25, 64)], [90, (9, 81)], [97, (16, 81)], [98, (49, 49)], [100, (36, 64)]]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Nota preliminar

Primero señalar que en tu pregunta mencionas el término "generador", pero tu código realmente no usa generadores. Esta palabra tiene un [significado muy concreto](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) en python. Un generador es una función que contiene una instrucción `yield`, que de alguna forma hace las veces de un `return`, pero sin dar por terminada a la función, que puede reanudarse más tarde y seguir por la línea siguiente al `yield`.

Un generador podría ser usado en tu caso para que, cada vez que le llamas, "genere" la siguiente suma de cuadrados (en lugar de ir guardándolas todas en una lista y al final devolver la lista), pero no es eso lo que estás haciendo.

### Mejoras en tu código

El código es correcto y, como tú dices, funciona, pero hay muchas posibles mejoras

#### Tipos de datos más apropiados

Los tipos que usas para resolver el problema son básicamente listas. Python tiene otros más apropiados para agilizar búsquedas.

Por ejemplo, tu lista almacena para cada número, su descomposición como suma de cuadrados. Así, un elemento de la lista tiene por ejemplo los valores `[65, (1, 64), (16, 49)]`, que indica que el `65` se descompone en la suma `1+64` y también `16+49`.

Una forma más eficiente sería que en lugar de una lista fuera un **diccionario**, cuya clave es cada número, y cada valor la lista de posibles descomposiciones en cuadrados. Así tu diccionario tendría (entre otras) la entrada `{ 65: [(1,64), (16,49)] }`

Verificar si un elemento está en el diccionario es mucho más eficiente que iterar por la lista para lo mismo. Basta mirar por ejemplo `if 65 in diccionario`.

Esto hace innecesaria tu función `comprobar()`.

```py
# PRIMERA MEJORA. DICCIONARIOS
def gen_raices1(min, max):
    diccionario = {}

    # Añade a la lista las sumas de raices.
    e1 = 1
    while e1 ** 2 <= max:
        for e2 in range(1, max):
            r1 = e1 ** 2
            r2 = e2 ** 2
            if r1+r2 > max:
              continue
            if r1+r2 not in diccionario:
              diccionario[r1+r2] = []
            if (r2,r1) not in diccionario[r1+r2]:
              diccionario[r1+r2].append((r1,r2))
        e1 += 1
    return diccionario
```

Queremos evitar que valores repetidos vayan a la misma clave del diccionario (es decir, que si ya sabemos que 17 es `1+16`, no se meta también el `16+1`). Por eso hago la comprobación de que `(r2, r1)` no esté ya en la lista asociada a `diccionario[r1+r2]`.

Otra posibilidad es usar **conjuntos** en lugar de listas. Un conjunto es un tipo de contenedor que, aunque le metas datos repetidos, sólo guarda una copia de cada uno. Por tanto podríamos hacer que los valores del diccionario sean conjuntos y meter allí las tuplas ordenadas (así `(1,16)` y  `(16,1)`, una vez ordenadas, ambas salen `(1,16)` y el conjunto sólo la meterá una vez.

El código quedaría así (tengo mis dudas de que esto sea más legible, casi prefiero la versión anterior):

```py
# SEGUNDA OPCIÓN. DICCIONARIOS y CONJUNTOS
def gen_raices2(min, max):
    diccionario = {}

    # Añade a la lista las sumas de raices.
    e1 = 1
    while e1 ** 2 <= max:
        for e2 in range(1, max):
            r1 = e1 ** 2
            r2 = e2 ** 2
            if r1+r2 > max:
              continue
            if r1+r2 not in diccionario:
              diccionario[r1+r2] = set()
            diccionario[r1+r2].add(tuple(sorted((r1,r2))))
        e1 += 1
    return diccionario
```

Finalmente, observa que tenemos que mirar si `r1+r2` estaba ya en el diccionario o no, ya que si no estaba, hay que crear una entrada nueva para él (una lista o un conjunto vacío), mientras que si ya estaba lo que hay que hacer es *añadir* a la lista (o conjunto) una pareja nueva.

Esto se simplifica haciendo uso de un **`defaultdict`**. Este es un diccionario que, cuando intentas acceder a una clave que no tiene, automáticamente crea una, del tipo que tu quieras. Por ejemplo, si seguimos con el caso en que estamos usando conjuntos:

```py
# TERCERA MEJORA. DEFAULTDICT y CONJUNTOS
from collections import defaultdict

def gen_raices3(min, max):
    diccionario = defaultdict(set)

    # Añade a la lista las sumas de raices.
    e1 = 1
    while e1 ** 2 <= max:
        for e2 in range(1, max):
            r1 = e1 ** 2
            r2 = e2 ** 2
            if r1+r2 > max:
              continue
            diccionario[r1+r2].add(tuple(sorted((r1,r2))))
        e1 += 1
    return diccionario
```

Observa que ya no tenemos el `if r1+r2 not in diccionario`. Directamente accedemos al elemento `[r1+r2]` como si existiera para actualizarlo. Si no existe, automáticamente se creará un conjunto vacío y luego se le añadirá la tupla en cuestión.

#### Reducir iteraciones innecesarias

En tu código varías `r1` desde 1 hasta `max`, y otro tanto para `r2`. Esto hace que estés computando muchos casos innnecesarios. Todos aquellos para los que `r1**2+r2**2` se pasa de `max` son descartados, pero con pararse a pensar un poco cuáles deberían ser los índices de los bucles, podrías haber evitado el calcularlos.

Fíjate que basta iterar `r1` desde 1 hasta la raíz cuadrada de `max`, ya que para todo `r1` mayor de esa raiz cuadrada tendrás que `r1**2` ya es mayor que `max`.

Por otro lado basta iterar `r2` comenzando en `r1` en lugar de comenzar en 1, para evitar así generar duplicados como `(1,16)` y `(16,1)`. Esto nos evita tener que usar conjuntos o tener que comprobar si la pareja en otro orden ya estaba guardada. ¡Es una gran optimización!. Además podemos parar la iteración al alcanzar la raiz cuadrada de `max-r1`, ya que para cualquier valor de `r2` superior a ese la suma `r1**2+r2**2` excedería `max`.

El siguiente código implementa estas ideas (para calcular la raíz cuadrada he elevado a 0.5):

```py
# TERCERA MEJORA. ELIMINAR ITERACIONES INNECESARIAS
def gen_raices3(min, max):
    diccionario = defaultdict(list)
    for e1 in range(1, int(max**0.5)):
        for e2 in range(e1, int((max-e1**2)**0.5)+1):
            r1 = e1**2
            r2 = e2 ** 2
            diccionario[r1+r2].append((r1, r2))
    return diccionario
```

**Optimización final**

Una pequeña optimización extra consiste en darse cuenta de que la instrucción `r1 = e1**2` se está ejecutando varias veces por estar dentro del segundo bucle, pero ya que en ese segundo bucle `r1` no varía, siempre sale lo mismo, por lo que la estamos recalculando innecesariamente. Podría calcularse antes de entrar en ese bucle:

```py
# CUARTA MEJORA. LIGERA OPTIMIZACION
from collections import defaultdict

def gen_raices4(min, max):
    diccionario = defaultdict(list)
    for e1 in range(1, int(max**0.5)):
        r1 = e1**2
        for e2 in range(e1, int((max-e1**2)**0.5)+1):
            r2 = e2 ** 2
            diccionario[r1+r2].append((r1, r2))
    return diccionario
```

## Resultado

En cualquiera de los casos anteriores, el resultado que devuelve la función es un diccionario (un `defaultdict` de hecho). Si lo imprimes sin más, no te saldrá ordenado de menor a mayor por sus claves (ya que en python los diccionarios no tienen orden prefijado). Si quieres que salga ordenado, puedes convertir el diccionario en una lista de tuplas (el primer elemento de la tupla sería la clave, el siguiente elemento su valor), y ordenar esa lista.

Por ejemplo:

```py
resultado = gen_raices4(1,100)
print(sorted(resultado.items()))
```

Para obtener:

```py
[(2, [(1, 1)]), (5, [(1, 4)]), (8, [(4, 4)]), (10, [(1, 9)]), (13, [(4, 9)]), (17, [(1, 16)]), (18, [(9, 9)]), (20, [(4, 16)]), (25, [(9, 16)]), (26, [(1, 25)]), (29, [(4, 25)]), (32, [(16, 16)]), (34, [(9, 25)]), (37, [(1, 36)]), (40, [(4, 36)]), (41, [(16, 25)]), (45, [(9, 36)]), (50, [(1, 49), (25, 25)]), (52, [(16, 36)]), (53, [(4, 49)]), (58, [(9, 49)]), (61, [(25, 36)]), (65, [(1, 64), (16, 49)]), (68, [(4, 64)]), (72, [(36, 36)]), (73, [(9, 64)]), (74, [(25, 49)]), (80, [(16, 64)]), (82, [(1, 81)]), (85, [(4, 81), (36, 49)]), (89, [(25, 64)]), (90, [(9, 81)]), (97, [(16, 81)]), (98, [(49, 49)]), (100, [(36, 64)])]
```

### Tiempos de ejecución

Como curiosidad, he cronometrado cuánto tarda en ejecutarse cada una de estas versiones, usando `timeit` (que ejecuta la función 1000 veces y se queda con el promedio de las tres mejores, para eliminar "ruido" aleatorio). Esto es lo que he obtenido:

- Tu versión: 745 µs
- Versión 1 (diccionarios de listas): 610 µs
- Versión 2 (diccionarios de conjuntos): 641 µs
- Versión 3 (reducir iteraciones): 44.7 µs
- Versión 4 (optimización final): 36.7 µs

**Conclusión**

Usar tipos más adecuados como el diccionario reduce la complejidad del código que queda más fácil de leer, pero tampoco reduce tanto el tiempo de ejecución, apenas unos 100 µs (en el caso de usar `set()` en vez de listas la cosa empeora ligeramente).

En cambio pararse a pensar cómo eliminar iteraciones innecesarias mejora los resultados espectacularmente, reduciendo el tiempo de ejecución en un orden de magnitud (dividir por 10). Fíjate que en este ejemplo son microsegundos, y parece que no merezca la pena, pero si el problema fuera más largo y tu versión tardara 20 minutos en terminar, la versión optimizada tardaría 1 minuto. ¡Compensa!

En todo caso, como dijo el gran sabio Donald Knuth, ***La optimización prematura es la raíz de todos los males***. Es decir, empieza por hacer un código legible y fácil de comprender y *sólo* si realmente necesitas que vaya mucho más rápido, plantéate cómo cambiarlo para mejorar su velocidad. Da prioridad a la legibilidad sobre la velocidad. Después de todo ¡por eso usamos python en vez de C! ;-)

Comment: Muchas gracias por la lección :)